# How get incremented value from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to get next id from table (auto_increment).

I could just use `SELECT * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

For example I get 50. But if we delete from table two items I will get 48 but correct one

will be 51. How get correct value even we something delete from table ?

Comment: All of the `show status` suggestions apply only if another query doesn't come along changing things between you getting your value, and using your value.

Comment: @gms8994: That's always an issue with this stuff. Concurrency is orthogonal, but you're right: it _is_ an issue to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
show table status like 'table_name'
```

next id value is in 'Auto_increment' field

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'` to fetch the auto_increment value. A simpler solution might be: `SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table`, but this is buggy if the last entry was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table'
```

The value you want is in the `Auto_increment` field.

Be careful about concurrency though: by the time you get around to using this value, some other client could have inserted into the table and thus your value is out of date. It's usually best to try to *not need this*.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1;
```

gets the last ID used in an insert in an autoincrement column + 1

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions for the next ID:

1) Select bigger value of a column with max function. Example: select max( id ) from table;
2) Using the command SHOW STATUS LIKE and get the correct index of array. Take a look: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: The first solution is broken if you previously deleted the "last" row.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're creating a race condition here.

Why exactly can you not insert the row you want to insert and then use LAST_INSERT_ID() to find it's ID?